# selectInput update inside renderUI function in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput, renderui

I have simplified my shiny app as follow:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyBS)



ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
  
  navbarPage("Demo",
             tabPanel("Home",
                      column(2,
                             selectInput(inputId = "s1",label = "select project",choices = c("1", "2", "3")),
                             uiOutput("sensor")
                             
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output,session){
  
  output$sensor <- renderUI({
    s = c(as.numeric((input$s1))^2,as.numeric((input$s1))^3)
    selectInput("t1",label ="Select",choices = ifelse(input$s1 == "1",c("x1","x2"),s ),multiple = FALSE)
    
  })   
}
```

I expect to get the `x1` and `x2` in second dropdown if my first selection is 1, otherwise either `4` and `8` or `9` and `27` should be the expected values in second dropdown.

But surprisingly, what I'm getting is just one value to select in second dropdown : if `1` I'm getting just `x1`, if `2` I have just `4` and if `3` I have just `9` !!

[image][image]

why the `selectInput` is not updating properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the online help for `ifelse`:

ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the element of test is TRUE or FALSE.

and

ifelse(test, yes, no)

In your case, `test` is `input$s1 == "1"`.  In other words, a (character) vector of length 1.  That's why you get only one value in your choices for `input$t1`.

To get what you want, try something like this (untested code):

```
if (input$s1 == "1") {
  choiceList <- c("x1","x2")
} else {
  choiceList <- c(as.numeric((input$s1))^2,as.numeric((input$s1))^3)
}
selectInput("t1",label ="Select",choices = choiceList, multiple = FALSE)
```

As an aside, you can get the same effect with `updateSelectInput` and no need for `renderUI` and `uiOutput`.

**Edit**

Here's the full code for the `uiOutput` version

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Demo",
             tabPanel("Home",
                      column(2,
                             selectInput(inputId = "s1",label = "select project",choices = c("1", "2", "3")),
                             uiOutput("sensor")
                             
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output,session){
  output$sensor <- renderUI({
    if (input$s1 == "1") {
      choiceList <- c("x1","x2")
    } else {
      choiceList <- c(as.numeric((input$s1))^2,as.numeric((input$s1))^3)
    }
    selectInput("t1",label ="Select",choices = choiceList, multiple = FALSE)
  })   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

and for the `updateSelectinput` version

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Demo",
             tabPanel("Home",
                      column(2,
                             selectInput(inputId = "s1",label = "select project",choices = c("1", "2", "3")),
                             selectInput("t1", label="Select", choices=c(), multiple = FALSE)
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$s1, {
    if (input$s1 == "1") {
      choiceList <- c("x1","x2")
    } else {
      choiceList <- c(as.numeric((input$s1))^2,as.numeric((input$s1))^3)
    }
    updateSelectInput(session, "t1",choices = choiceList)
  })   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Personally, I prefer the latter as it seems cleaner.